# INSERT INTO SELECT and other data

Tags: sql, sqlite, node-sqlite3

I want to copy data from first table to second table and add other data to other columns,

First table: (id, name)
Second table: (id, name, turn)

Result: s.id = f.id, s.name = f.name, s.turn = '?' (my other data)

Example (may be) sql:

```
INSERT INTO second (SELECT id, name FROM first), 'other'
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO second (id, name, turn)
    SELECT id, name, 'other'
    FROM first;
```

Note the listing of the column names for the `INSERT`.  This is not strictly required, but highly recommended to avoid unexpected problems.